# Tablas: mostrar hileras ocultas al seleccionar con el teclado

Tags: javascript, function, table

Tengo una tabla con una gran cantidad de ítems. Como es muy larga, en la versión real tiene una altura máxima con una barra de desplazamiento vertical. He incorporado [este script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?74566-Using-the-up-and-down-arrow-keys-to-select-a-table-row) para deplazarme verticalmente por la tabla usando las flechas del teclado después de seleccionar una fila. Funciona perfectamente.

Pero, al tener filas ocultas, no encuentro el modo de hacer que estas aparezcan desde la parte inferior de la tabla una vez que llego a la última. La selección desde el teclado avanza sobre las hileras ocultas pero no aparecen en la parte visible de la tabla. Lo mismo en la parte superior si la parte visible de la tabla son las filas inferiores.

```js
    (function() {
        var trows = document.getElementById('mstrTable').rows, t = trows.length, trow, nextrow,
        addEvent = (function(){return window.addEventListener? function(el, ev, f){
                el.addEventListener(ev, f, false); //modern browsers
            }:window.attachEvent? function(el, ev, f){
                el.attachEvent('on' + ev, function(e){f.apply(el, [e]);}); //IE 8 and less
            }:function(){return;}; //a very old browser (IE 4 or less, or Mozilla, others, before Netscape 6), so let's skip those
        })();

        while (--t > -1) {
            trow = trows[t];
            trow.className = 'normal';
            addEvent(trow, 'click', highlightRow);
        }//end while

        function highlightRow(gethighlight) { //now dual use - either set or get the highlighted row
            gethighlight = gethighlight === true;
            var t = trows.length;
            while (--t > -1) {
                trow = trows[t];
                if(gethighlight && trow.className === 'highlighted'){return t;}
                else if (!gethighlight && trow !== this) { trow.className = 'normal'; }
            }//end while

            return gethighlight? null : this.className = this.className === 'highlighted'? 'normal' : 'highlighted';
        }//end function

        function movehighlight(way, e){
            e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;
            var idx = highlightRow(true); //gets current index or null if none highlighted
            if(typeof idx === 'number'){//there was a highlighted row
                idx += way; //increment\decrement the index value
                if(idx && (nextrow = trows[idx])){ return highlightRow.apply(nextrow); } //index is > 0 and a row exists at that index
                else if(idx){ return highlightRow.apply(trows[1]); } //index is out of range high, go to first row
                return highlightRow.apply(trows[trows.length - 1]); //index is out of range low, go to last row
            }
            return highlightRow.apply(trows[way > 0? 1 : trows.length - 1]); //none was highlighted - go to 1st if down arrow, last if up arrow
        }//end function

        function processkey(e){
            switch(e.keyCode){
                case 38: {//up arrow
                    return movehighlight(-1, e)
                }
                case 40: {//down arrow
                    return movehighlight(1, e);
                }
                default: {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }//end function

        addEvent(document, 'keydown', processkey);

    }/* end function */)();//execute function and end script
```

```css
    table {border-collapse: collapse; display:block; max-height: 168px; overflow-y:auto; border:2px solid cyan; width:fit-content; margin: 0 auto;}


    td {width:120px;height:30px;border:1px solid gray;}


    tr.normal td {
        background-color: lightgray;

    }
    tr.highlighted td {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <table id="mstrTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Mira sobre el método `scrollIntoView()`, debes usarlo sobre el `<tr>` que reciba el resaltado. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: No ha funcionado, o no supe hacerlo funcionar